# mobile-angular-ui + laravel to phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, laravel

I programmed a backend in laravel + a frontend in mobile-angular-ui, and everythings works fine so far.

Now what I want to do is add the possibility of push notifications. To do that, I thought, I'll try phonegap to "convert" the whole thing into a native app, and then somehow wrap push-notifications around the whole thing.

two questions:

- is this a valid approach in the first place, or would something else be suited better ? (for example embed the web application in some container in a xcode app ? or something completely else ?)
- how can i get my webapp working with phonegap ? (i can't put all into the www/ directory of a newly created phonegap app, for example due to the fact, that laravel stores the index.php in a public/ directory)

Answer (score 0):

I think its a valid approach. I am using cordova, tested ionic as well for the same approach. I like the fact that i dont have to code for both ios and android same.

You have to write ajax request for your server like the laravel script you have mentioned here. The application will fetch data from the server and update the states of embeded webview. The www/ will containe all the js, css, and angular mvc.

Hope it helps.